# aws cognito check if user email exists in UserPool

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, authentication, email, aws-lambda

What I'm trying to do ?

Run on all users and check if the email exists in the cognito user pool

What actually happens ?

I get the following error:

```
Custom auth lambda trigger is not configured for the user pool.
```

on Edit app client information,
I added the following permissions:

[image]

my question:

**Is it necessary to configure lamda in AWS in order to receive all users?**